# pivot lapply data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

given the following dt:

```
Category <- c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','B','B')                       
Amount <- c(10,20,30,15,20,40, 50, 80,20,10)                     
ID <- c('x01','x01','x02','x03','x03','x04','x05','x06','x07','x08') 
dt_1 <- data.table(Category, Amount, ID) 
dt_1
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
Category <- c('A','B')
NumRecords <- c(4,6)
TotalAmount <- c(140,155)
CountUniqueID <- c(3,5)
dt_2 <- data.table(Category, NumRecords, TotalAmount, CountUniqueID)
dt_2
```

possibly extending adjusting the following code that uses lapply:

```
ColsBy <- c("Category")
ColsSummary <- c("Amount")
dt_2 <- dt_1[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by = ColsBy, .SDcols = ColsSummary ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt_1[, .(NumRecords = .N,
         TotalAmount = sum(Amount),
         CountUniqueId = uniqueN(ID)),
     by = .(Category)]

   Category NumRecords TotalAmount CountUniqueId
1:        A          4         140             3
2:        B          6         155             5
```